# Set Environment Variables with Puppet

Tags: shell, ubuntu, vagrant, puppet

I am using vagrant with puppet to set up virtual machines for development environments.  I would like to simply set a few environment variables in the .pp file.  Using virtual box and a vagrant base box for Ubuntu 64 bit.

I have this currently.

```
$bar = 'bar'

class foobar {
   exec { 'foobar':
     command => "export Foo=${bar}",
   }
}
```

but when provisioning I get an error: Could not find command 'export'.

This seems like it should be simple enough am I missing some sort of require or path for the exec type?  I noticed in the documentation there is an environment option to set up environment variables, should I be using that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you only need the variables available in the puppet run for all exec resources, whats wrong with :

```
Exec { environment => [ "foo=$bar" ] }
```

?

Comment: exec statements wont export the variable for when he logs in to the server.

Comment: I know that - thats why i said 'if you only need the variables available in the puppet run'. The question does not state that the variables are required to be set in user shells

Answer (score 16):

Simplest way to acomplish this is to put your env vars in /etc/environment, this ensures they are available to everything (or pretty much everything).

Something like this:

```
class example($somevar) {
    file { "/etc/environment":
        content => inline_template("SOMEVAR=${somevar}")
    }
}
```

Reason for having the class parameterised is so you can target it from hiera with automatic variable lookup (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup) ... if you're sticking something in /etc/environment, it's usually best if you actually make it environment specific.

*note: I've only tested this on ubuntu*

Comment: I like the simple & succinct fix much more than I dislike that this pollutes my `/etc/environment`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The way I got around it is to also use /etc/profile.d:

```
$bar = 'bar'
file { "/etc/profile.d/my_test.sh":
  content => "export Foo=${bar}",
  mode    => 755
}
```

This ensures that everytime you login (ex ssh), the variable $MYVAR gets exported to your environment. After you apply through puppet and login (ex ssh localhost), echo $Foo would return bar

Answer (score 4):

You can set an environment variable by defining it on a line in `/etc/environment` and you can ensure a line inside a file using `file_line` in puppet. Combine these two into the following solution:

```
file_line { "foo_env_var":
    ensure  => present,
    line    => "Foo=${bar}",
    path    => "/etc/environment",
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution if you need to coexist with other environment variables in your /etc/environment file.  You can also use the match parameter to ensure that the line isn't duplicated after it is changed.

Comment: How would you use that variable? Just `$foo_env_var` ?

Comment: `foo_env_var` is the name of the line used by puppet only. The environment variable being set here is `Foo` so using it will be like `$Foo` - eg: `echo $Foo`

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following, which sets the environment variable for this `exec`:

```
class foobar {
   exec { 'foobar' :
     command => "/bin/bash -c \"export Foo=${bar}\"",
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I actually found that solution.  While it removes the error about the command not being found it unfortunately does not produce the expected result.  The environment variable Foo is not set when I ssh into the virtual machine.

Comment: This is a noop. It modifies the environment of a shell that has been forked specifically for this `exec` resource. This shell then immediately terminates. The export has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work while preserving existing contents of the /etc/environment file:

**/code/environments/{environment}/manifests/environment/variable.pp:**

```
define profile::environment::variable (
    $variable_name,
    $value,
    $ensure => present,
) {
    file_line { $variable_name:
        path   => '/etc/environment',
        ensure => $ensure,
        line   => "$variable_name=$value",
        match  => "$variable_name=",
    }
}
```

Usage (in the body of a node manifest):

```
profile::environment::variable { 'JAVA_HOME':
    variable_name  => 'JAVA_HOME',
    value => '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was able to set the `PS1` prompt value and add it to my `.bashrc` file like this:

```
$PS1 = '\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\] \$ '
```

and within a class:

```
exec {"vagrant-prompt":
  unless =>  "grep -F 'export PS1=\"${PS1}\"' ${HOME_DIR}/.bashrc",
  command => "echo 'export PS1=\"${PS1}\"' >> ${HOME_DIR}/.bashrc",
  user => "${APP_USER}",
}
```

The `-F` makes `grep` it interpret it as a fixed string.  Otherwise it won't find it and keeps adding to the `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation. This has the advantage that `stdlib` isn't required (as is with `file_line` solutions), and the existing content of `/etc/environment` is preserved:

```
exec {'echo foo=bar>>/etc/environment':
  onlyif => 'test -f /etc/environment',
  unless => 'grep "foo=bar" /etc/environment',
  path   => '/usr/bin',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/exec.html

```
class envcheck {

  file { '/tmp/test':
    ensure => file,
  }

  exec { 'foobar':
    command     => 'echo $bar >> /tmp/test',
    environment => ['bar=foo'],
    path        => ['/bin/'],
  }
}
```

1. Creating an empty file because an echo would happen in the shell Puppet is running the command in, not the one we're looking at.
2. Setting an environment variable bar to equal foo.
3. Setting the path for the echo binary, this isn't normally necessary for system commands but useful to know about.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to set environment variables for all resources with puppet is to predefine them before the puppet run or use this module:
https://github.com/rbramwell/set_env

The most accepted answer here is technically not right.
This is a resource reference which modifies all "exec" resources and add the environment parameter to them.
https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_resources.html#adding-or-modifying-attributes

But other resources like "package" resources won't get affected by them. In my case I have an ugly vendor RPM which requires an environment variable at installation which I cannot provide via puppet temporary, so I needed the linked module to get it working.