# How to set JAVA_HOME using puppet script on windows?

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet and I want to install Java using puppet.
I have standalone puppet installed on my windows systems.

I was able to copy the binaries into specific folder using puppet but not able to set the path.
Can anyone please help me to set the simple `JAVA_HOME/environment` variable using puppet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Environment Variables with Puppet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411795/set-environment-variables-with-puppet)

Comment: I need script specific for windows.

Comment: seth PATH=%PATH%,C:\ and so on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: @vidit most definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: @FelixFrank - Can you please tell me why it is not?  I don't know much about Puppet. How's setting `JAVA_HOME` different from setting an env variable?

Comment: @vidit it is not, but the question you linked concerns itself with the environment on a Linux system, which is fundamentally different from how Windows goes about it. Even though Puppet tries to abstract from this kind of thing, this is not possible for all use cases, and environment variables are one of them.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/badgerious/windows_env) for managing environment variables in Windows.

For example

```
windows_env { 'JAVA_HOME':
  ensure    => 'C:\JDK',
  mergemode => clobber,
}
```

The README even presents a specific example

```
windows_env { 'JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.6.0_02':
  type => REG_EXPAND_SZ,
}
```