# Set an env var for only the provisioner

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I need an environment variable added to the front of `$PATH` that:

1. Doesn't last beyond the provisioning run.
2. Is dependent i.e. something will be installed earlier in the run that is *then* is available via `$PATH`, so I can't set it globally [as this cookbook says to](http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/set-global-exec-path.html).

I tried [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18417598/335847):

```
Exec { environment => [ "foo=$bar" ] }
```

but I get the error `Error: All resource specifications require names`. When I add a name I get other errors about syntax, for which my fiddling around to fix just gives me other errors (the error `Syntax error at '}'; expected '}'` is my favourite!)

I've tried using `export` to set it, but I see: `Error: Could not find command 'export'`

I've tried using `set` and `setenv` too, with similar results. There must be a straightforward way to do this, but I can't find it.

### Edit

Just to add, these are the available shells:

```
$ cat /etc/shells
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

zsh is part of the provisioning, but it could be a requirement of the answer, if needs be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few ways for this, but the best I found was to use Hiera. I read quite a few blogs on how to set this up with Vagrant too, but [this was the best](http://terrarum.net/blog/masterless-puppet-with-vagrant.html) I found.

#### My project directory layout

```
Vagrantfile
pp/
  manifests/
  modules/
  data/
    hiera.yml
    common.yml
```

#### Vagrantfile

The relevant part of the Vagrantfile:

```
  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "pp/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "pp/modules/custom"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "default.pp"
    puppet.hiera_config_path = "pp/data/hiera.yaml"
  end
```

I've no idea yet why there needs to be a `hiera.yaml` which points to a `common.yaml`, but that's the way it is.

#### hiera.yaml

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml

:hierarchy:
  - "common"

:yaml:
  :datadir: '/vagrant/pp/data'
```

#### common.yaml

```
---
ruby_version: "2.3.0"
ruby_prefix: "/opt/rubies"
...
```

#### Then in a manifest

```
$ruby_version = hiera("ruby_version")
$ruby_prefix = hiera("ruby_prefix")
$ruby_dir_fullpath = "${ruby_prefix}/ruby-${ruby_version}"
```

Seems like a lot of effort to me, but again, that's the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Added to the front of your path, you want to add your resource default like this I believe:

```
Exec { environment => "PATH=value:$PATH", }
```

This could be incorrect, but I do know that it will replace the variables you set, not append to them by default. More details at https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec-attribute-environment